# Adverb in a sentence

Tags: grammar, adverb

I would like to say the following:

> He arrived home by coming by the street.

my atempt is this:

> Er kommt kommend die Straße zu Hause an

I used the participle in present tense of the verb *kommen* as the adverb.
Is this correct?

Comment: Er kam über die Straße zuhause an.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that neither the English example nor the German translation makes a lot of sense to me.

Maybe a more useful real-life example using the same constructs to start discussion on would be

*Der Täter kam, Nebenstraßen nutzend, in seinem Versteck an.*

(*using side roads the culprit arrived at his hideout*)

This would maybe accepted as a proper German sentence, although it is still disputable:

Arriving in the hideout is a certain point in time, while using side roads is a continuous action. You seem to be trying to replicate the English continuous form with an adverbial construct. This isn't quite right, as there is no such thing in German. The sentence above implicates he was using side roads when he arrived, not necessarily before (although it is clear from the context what was actually intended).

*Über Nebenstrassen erreichte der Täter sein Versteck* would be evading all of those problems and construct a correct German sentence.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. What you constructed there means “he comes coming the street“ which doesn't even make sense in English. Besides, the tense of the verb is wrong.

I'm not quite sure what exactly you are trying to express (the English sentence also seems to be a little rough).

The correct use of the participle would be

> …kommend von der Straße…

The correct verb tense would be:

> Er kam…

With a little more information about what you actually want to say, we could complete the sentence.